# THREE.JS Loader onProgress only fires once after loading is complete

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

How can I make sure when I am loading a model to get regular updates on the loading progress so I can build a loading icon. I have followed every turorial I could find but with every answer the onProgress method only fires once as soon as the loading is finished.

My loader code in typescript:

```
// Load manager
private manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

// Set up loading manager (in constructor of class)
this.manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
  console.log( item, loaded, total );
};


// Load OBJ File from Server
private loadFile(path) {
   let loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(this.manager)
   loader.load(path, (obj)=>{
      this.model = obj;
      this.boundingBox = new THREE.BoxHelper(obj)
      this.scene.add(this.model);
   });
}
```

The log:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/file/largeModels/z3.obj 1 1
```

I only get this one log after te model was loaded. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
    // Load manager

    private manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();

    // Set up loading manager (in constructor of class)
    this.manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
      console.log( item, loaded, total );
    };


    // Load OBJ File from Server
    private loadFile(path) {
       let loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(this.manager)
       loader.load(path, (obj)=>{
          this.model = obj;
          this.boundingBox = new THREE.BoxHelper(obj)
          this.scene.add(this.model);
       },this.onProgress, this.onError ); // onProgress, onError added....
    }

    private onProgress ( xhr ) {
      if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete) + '% downloaded' );
      }
    };

    private onError ( xhr ) {
      console.log("Will call when error occure.");
    };
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. thx. Do you know if there is a similar method for the actuall loading of the OBJ Loader. Since now I have a progressbar for the download but not the loading...

Comment: I don't get an error. It's just that with large models after the download has reached 100% there is still a pause where the model is being loaded and displayed. Can I see progress there?

Comment: approx how much time it takes after loading? Could you create jsfiddle link?